# save foursquare oauth token on Android

Tags: android, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, foursquare

I was able to get oauth token from FourSquare by following a tutorial given in their website, but after getting the oauth token from Foursquare on Android, can someone please suggest me where the oauth token should be stored in Android. Is there any database inside android where tokens like these are stored.

If someone could also suggest me a help or tutorial page, it would be very helpful.

Also, Is it possible to use the google-oauth-java-client library for FourSquare authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should Use `SharedPrefrences` for store token.Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

And Also Example

http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html